# Breakage in highchart generation

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, highcharts

This is my json data

```
[
    {
        "project_title":"sdsdsd",
        "project_ref_id":"112",
        "amount":"232323.00",
        "months":"Mar-2015"
    },{
        "project_title":"test project 44",
        "project_ref_id":"113",
        "amount":"13000.00",
        "months":"Feb-2016"
    },{
        "project_title":"sdsdsd",
        "project_ref_id":"112",
        "amount":"50000.00",
        "months":"Mar-2016"
    },{
        "project_title":"hello wolrd",
        "project_ref_id":"111",
        "amount":"30000.00",
        "months":"Mar-2016"
    },{
        "project_title":"sdsdsd",
        "project_ref_id":"112",
        "amount":"2000.00",
        "months":"Apr-2016"
    },{
        "project_title":"road construction",
        "project_ref_id":"108",
        "amount":"1000.00",
        "months":"Apr-2016"
    },{
        "project_title":"road construction",
        "project_ref_id":"108",
        "amount":"299090.00",
        "months":"May-2016"
    },{
        "project_title":"sdsdsd",
        "project_ref_id":"112",
        "amount":"384357.00",
        "months":"May-2016"
    },{
        "project_title":"road construction",
        "project_ref_id":"108",
        "amount":"2365236.00",
        "months":"Jun-2016"
    }
]
```

I am trying to generate a high chart with month in x-axis, amount in y-axis

This is the code which I tried http://jsfiddle.net/4bsvjzus/5/

Thechart which is generated is correct, but there is a breakage in the line.

If you see in the above fiddle code. The project with name `project1` has the amount `232323` in `mar-2015` and `50000` in `mar-2016`, `2000` in `apr-2016`, `384357` in `may-2016`.There is no data for project `project1` in `feb-2016`, hence the graph breaked at `feb-2016`, whereas there is data for `feb-2016` for other projects.

Hence whenever there is no data for a particular month the graph is breaking and continuing from the month which has data.

The graph must not break in the middle. If there is no data for a month, the graph must show a point with value `0` for that month

Comment: Can you modify your data to contain '0' values for the missing months?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [incorrect generation of highcharts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37547332/incorrect-generation-of-highcharts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember answering [a very similar question of you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37547332/incorrect-generation-of-highcharts/37555835#37555835) a few days back. It also had sparse y-values problem to break the graph. I copy here the very same solution which apparently works just fine. The `(new Array(months.length)).fill(0).map((e,i) => i === months.indexOf(c.months)  ? c.amount*1 : e)` line is in charge to form an initial array filled with zeros and with a value for the months index position. (i.e. Jan value at index 0 Dec value at index 11)

```js
var data = [{"project_title":"sdsdsd","project_ref_id":"112","amount":"232323.00","months":"Mar-2015"},{"project_title":"test project 44","project_ref_id":"113","amount":"13000.00","months":"Feb-2016"},{"project_title":"sdsdsd","project_ref_id":"112","amount":"50000.00","months":"Mar-2016"},{"project_title":"hello wolrd","project_ref_id":"111","amount":"30000.00","months":"Mar-2016"},{"project_title":"sdsdsd","project_ref_id":"112","amount":"2000.00","months":"Apr-2016"},{"project_title":"road construction","project_ref_id":"108","amount":"1000.00","months":"Apr-2016"},{"project_title":"road construction","project_ref_id":"108","amount":"299090.00","months":"May-2016"},{"project_title":"sdsdsd","project_ref_id":"112","amount":"384357.00","months":"May-2016"},{"project_title":"road construction","project_ref_id":"108","amount":"2365236.00","months":"Jun-2016"}],
months = data.reduce((p,c) => ~p.indexOf(c.months) ? p : p.concat(c.months),[]),
series = data.reduce((p,c) => { var f = p.find(f => f.name == c.project_title);
                                !!f ? f.data[months.indexOf(c.months)] = c.amount*1
                                    : p.push({name: c.project_title,
                                              data: (new Array(months.length)).fill(0).map((e,i) => i === months.indexOf(c.months) ? c.amount*1 : e)});
                                return p;
                               },[]);
    $('#container').highcharts({
        title: {
            text: 'Retaielr Clicks',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Date',
            x: -20
        },
         xAxis: {
            categories: months
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Clicks'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
              //  valueSuffix: '°C'
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: series
    });
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```